# How do I edit JPG File Title, Subject, Comments, and Tags/Keywords?

Tags: vb.net, tags, metadata, keyword, jpeg

How do I edit JPG File Title, Subject, Comments, and Tags/Keyowrds?*

I have already tried asking this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595884/vb-net-renaming-file-and-retagging-edit-image-metadata-meta-tags):

The Exif information provided was helpful, but in the end did not actually solve the real riddle I was working on. So I'll take another angle at describing the desired result:

I want my VB.NET app to allow me to edit the following details of a Jfile (see image):

Title, Subject, Comments, and Tags/Keyowrds

- [I had a handy image to include but not enough points to post it. Weak.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR8Gk.jpg)
- RIGHT CLICK A .JPG IN WINDOWS and select PROPERTIES
- Win XP: Select the "Summary Tab" and Look at the "Description" group
- Win7/Server 2008R2: "Details Tab" and look at "Description" group

Can anyone explain how to edit those fields through VB.net in Visual Studio?

EDIT:

The ultimate goal is to use the image viewer/editer that I built, to sort thousands of images of random webjunk I have collected over the years. 
Upon viewing the image (say "00001.jpg") and figureing out what it is ("ceiling cat sends son" picture of a lol cat), I want to type in the description (already done in the form). When I hit enter I want to rename the file (from "00001.jpg" to "ceiling-cat-sends-son.jpg", then fill in the keywords, title, subject, and comments fields with the same data: "ceiling cat sends son".

This will help with local indexing and with my (later) automating a SQL server referential database for use with site wide searches on my website. The ONLY thing I can't seem to figure out is how to modify those four fields as if I had right-clicked the file and added the keywords.

Comment: While you can certainly modify the image headers directly, I recommend that you create separate metadata records instead. You can create a record that will store those kinds of information, as well as a path to where the file is located. This has the advantage of being able to perform a search without having to examine the headers of every single image file every time.

Comment: Understood. And Agreed. The plan is to rename every one of thousands of images, one at a time, by visual inspection, then typing the description. I can easily push this to the SQL database, but I'm just hoping to add the same data to the image itself at the same time, so I only go through the image once. That way if the image gets emailed elsewhere, it can still be found easily. So, any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I can only offer you a starting point, since I don't use VB.Net and I only read EXIF data. In C#, if you open file in a `System.Drawing.Image` instance using:

```
Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("path/to/file.jpg");
```

You can access the raw EXIF data by using `image.GetPropertyItem(0x0112)`, where the list of all available property items are listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534418%28VS.85%29.aspx

Likewise, there's an `image.SetPropertyItem(0x0112)` method, but I think that will only set it in memory and you will have to save a **copy** of the image in order to write it out. I think what you want though is the ability to modify the EXIF without touching the actual image, which I do not know how to do.

### Using metadata

As I've said in my comment, I recommend that instead of editing the image header information, you should create a `Media` class that holds that kind of information:

```
public class Media
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public string PathToFile { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would store this record in the database, which makes it really easy to search on. If you need the actual file, use the `PathToFile` property to locate it.