# How do I edit JPG File Title, Subject, Comments, and Tags/Keywords? - Follow Up

Tags: c#, vb.net, image, exif

This question relates to **[this original forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882130/how-do-i-edit-jpg-file-title-subject-comments-and-tags-keywords/4882207#4882207):**

I am looking for clarification on the implementation of the answer here.  I took the idea of `image.SetPropertyItem(0x0112)` to try to access some properties in a photo of mine.  My issue is that the properties are written as *0x0112 etc...*, but the SetPropertyItem parameter calls for an integer.  I have tried converting the *0x0112* property IDs into integers, but I have not been able to actually get a known property to show up for me.

This is trival but has me stuck.  Any clarification would be great to help me along the way.  I have been trying to use the IDs from   [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534418%28VS.85%29.aspx) to read and eventually add properties to my photos.

Comment: 0x0112 *is* an integer. It's just a hex representation of one. It's equivalent to 274 decimal.

Comment: `int propId = 0x0112;` is perfectly valid C#, so you shouldn't have to convert anything.

Comment: ... and if you're using VB.NET it would be `&H112` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240587/declaring-hex-constant-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to use exif properties for a PropertyItem

```
Public Enum EXIFProperty
    Title = 40091
    Author = 40093
    Keywords = 40094
    Comments = 40092
End Enum

Dim exifProperty As EXIFProperty
Dim propertyItem As PropertyItem

propertyItem.Id = CInt(exifProperty.Title)
```