# VB.NET Retrieving Meta Tags from an Image

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, metadata, meta-tags

Alright I've been messing with this for a few days now, and I found this topic here on the board.

[VB.NET Renaming File and Retagging / Edit Image MetaData / Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595884/vb-net-renaming-file-and-retagging-edit-image-metadata-meta-tags)

After reading through that, and getting the library that one of the answers spoke of, I easily inserted the code into my project and everything was working decently well. However the entire reason I was looking for such a thing was to get the 'Keywords/Tags' metadata, and this code no matter what I did wouldn't give me what I was looking for.

Knowing that the 'Keywords' address was &H9C9E I was able to do the following.

```
    Dim test As String = EX.GetPropertyString(&H9C9E)
    MsgBox(test)
```

That worked to a point, I messed with it for awhile but no matter what I changed I was unable to get that to display anymore than the very first character of the tags. For example I placed 'Test' in the keywords and it simply returned 'T'. I looked through the coding of the library, but I wasn't able to figure out why it wasn't returning everything. I've tried changing the content in tags in an attempt at getting it to load, and I've tried with a few different images though it always returned only the first character.

Also when I attempted to make changes to the keywords data, I was unable to get it to display anything even though the following code worked with everything else.

```
    EX.SetPropertyString(ExifWorks.TagNames.ExifUserComment, "This Worked")
    EX.GetBitmap.Save(SaveLoc + "1decfabd90e2355eac81b3f9735e10e3.jpg")
```

So my question is, why is it only displaying the very first character and why isn't it able to save to the address?

EDIT:

After playing with it a bit I was able to get the contents of 'Keywords' to appear, though it isn't exactly ideal.

```
    Dim test = EX.GetProperty(&H9C9E)
    Dim test2 = EX.Encoding.GetCharCount(test)
    Dim test3 = EX.Encoding.GetChars(test)

    Dim tolnum As Integer = test2
    Dim cur As Integer = -1

    While tolnum > 0
        cur = cur + 1
        tolnum = tolnum - 1
        MsgBox(test3(cur))
    End While
```

For example with 'TEST' in the 'Keywords' I get 'T;E;S;T;;;;'
; Is marking the unknown characters/blank msgboxes.

Comment: The `GetPropertyString` function calls code that uses the current encoding variable to truncate null characters.  Have you tried playing with the `EX.Encoding` property?  Your test properties may be in ASCII or non-UTF8 (the default in that library).

Comment: No I have not, however I will give that a go and report back.

Comment: Playing around with the 'EX.Encoding' property yielded no results of relevance, was there anything in particular you had in mind with that property? @Grim

Comment: Revised: Actually after playing with it a bit more, I managed to get the text from the field, and it seemed you were right in the idea that it has some characters that cannot be displayed. Anyways, I'll post my code above to show what I did.

Comment: I've just modified the example code from CodeProject, and added in the Keywords field to try and reproduce.  I got what you just got - the Console output shows a space between each character.  I suspect it's the encoding, but I'm not very familiar with all the varieties...!

Comment: @Grim Yeah that is sort of my issue, I'm not sure exactly what sort of encoding is being used, nor am I sure what characters could be hidden right there. It would probably be possible to parse out the bits that are missing, but that still leaves the actual saving changes to the Keywords field.

Comment: A bit of debugging has just told me it's Unicode, as opposed to UTF8.  If you set the Encoding to Unicode, does it ruin the rest of the fields?  If so, you're going to have to modify the library to better detect the encoding used in the file and interpret it appropriately.  Then the saving should be simple - with the encoding in reverse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file
That might help - lots of links to detection stuff.

Comment: @Grim Well, the actual getting the information from Unicode is easy.. Just working on actually saving it in a Unicode format at this point. That is a useful link however.

Comment: @Grim After one final addition it did work, though the data that was in the Keyword field remained, and instead a new tag was added. Thank you for all of the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright with the help of Grim I've been able to correct the issue and find an answer. This is the solution I used to solve my issue.

Since the 'Keywords' field is Unicode I had to ensure that when reading the information from the field it was Encoded with Unicode, and when saving I needed to ensure it was converted to Unicode before saving.

The Code:

```
Sub Test()

    ''Get SaveLoc from settings
    Dim SaveLoc As String
    SaveLoc = My.Settings.SaveLocation

    ''Select photo to edit/view
    Dim Bitmap As String
    Bitmap = SaveLoc + "\Test\" + "1decfabd90e2355eac81b3f9735e10e3.jpg"

    ''Use ExifWorks library
    Dim EX As New ExifWorks(Bitmap)

    ''Set Encoding to Unicode
    Dim enc As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding

    ''Get data from Keywords field
    Dim keywords = EX.GetProperty(&H9C9E)

    ''Use Unicode encoding to get the contents currently within Keywords
    Dim decode = enc.GetChars(keywords)

    ''View the current tags, decoded from Unicode
    MsgBox(decode)

    ''Set Encoding to Unicode
    Dim enc2 As Encoding = Encoding.Unicode

    ''Tags to Add
    Dim tags As String = "These; are; testing; tags"

    ''Encode to Unicode and switch to Bytes
    Dim Data() As Byte = enc2.GetBytes(tags & vbNullChar)

    ''Append the Keywords field with the new tags
    EX.SetProperty(&H9C9E, Data, ExifWorks.ExifDataTypes.UnsignedByte)

    ''Save the changes
    EX.GetBitmap.Save(SaveLoc + "\Test\" + "NEW1decfabd90e2355eac81b3f9735e10e3.jpg")

End Sub
```